# Understading general Game Looping

Tags: java, rendering, game-engine, frame-rate, game-loop

I've been reading some materials over internet related this topic but I'm still lazy. [This](https://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/game-loop.html) was the last I read and got me the best knowledge about how to struct the general idea, however, with my tests, I don't know if I got the loop works fine for its propose.

So far, I tried to set up this test:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    double MS_PER_UPDATE = 1e3/60; //is this representing 60 FPS?
    long elapsed;
    long current;
    double lag = 0.0;
    long previous = System.currentTimeMillis();

    int frames = 0;
    long timer = System.currentTimeMillis();

    try {
        while (true){
            current = System.currentTimeMillis();
            elapsed = current - previous;
            previous = current;
            lag += elapsed;

            //performs game input update here
            Thread.sleep(2);

            while (lag >= MS_PER_UPDATE){
                //performs game update here
                Thread.sleep(10);
                lag -= MS_PER_UPDATE;
            }

            //performs render game here
            Thread.sleep(6);
            frames++;
            if (System.currentTimeMillis() - timer >= 1000){
                System.out.println(frames + " frames per second?");
                frames = 0;
                timer = System.currentTimeMillis();
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Note that I placed some `Thread.sleep()` calls to try "simulate" a delay of those methods in a "real" context. However I'm getting some results like on the console:

```
19 frames per second?
13 frames per second?
17 frames per second?
21 frames per second?
21 frames per second?
12 frames per second?
```

Is my machine really slow in performing this operations or is the `sleep()` method being very unprecise or is my FPS measurement wrong? Plase, let me know if the above code can be used for simple game experiments. Thanks in advance!

Comment: So, one of the things you loop needs to try and do, is "wait" a specific amount of time between each frame.  If the target is 60fps that's ~16.7 milliseconds between each frame.  So, each "update cycle" needs to be performed within that time frame, otherwise you 1) need to optimise the work flow and 2) not delay the next frame.  So, this means if it takes ~10milliseconds to update and render the frame, you should wait ~6 milliseconds before you start the next cycle ...

Comment: not sure what the "lag" cycle is for, but I'd probably just use the "desired time per frame" - "time it took to render this frame" and if it's greater then 0, sleep on it

Comment: Sleep is not a great way to control loop timings, especially very tiny ones. It's not very accurate. Definitely google the topic, it will be very illuminating. [This](https://gafferongames.com/post/fix_your_timestep/) is the quintessential guide on how to do a game loop better. Game programming patterns is a great source, by the way. Definitely continue reading.